# How to run PyTorch inference on multiple models in parallel?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have 16 models (3 layer neural networks) with different parameters. I want to load all 16 models to device and run inference of 16 different inputs on the 16 models in parallel. Is there a way to do this in PyTorch?

Comment: do you have multiple gpus?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.